How do I pivot and transform a Grafana table that is formed using two queries
I have a Grafana visualization that uses a mixed data source using an Azure Data Source (using KQL) and the Infinity data source for an API.
The Azure connection is called first to get some data which looks like this -



Timestamp
Property
Point
Value




2024-08-29 02:30:45
1000
Read Data
0


2024-08-29 02:30:45
1001
Read Data
10


2024-08-29 01:45:12
5000
Write Data
50



Now, I have an API which has data in this format:
[
    {
        "Name": "Currently Loaded Equipment Model",
        "Point": "Read Data",
        "Property": 1000
    },
    {
        "Name": "Remote Leaving Chilled Liquid Setpoint",
        "Point": "Write Data",
        "Property": 5000
    }, ...et cetera

I can join them to get this using Merge series/timetables transformation: (this is all example data, just to give an idea)



Timestamp
Property
Point
Name
Value




2024-08-29 02:30:45
1000
Read Data
Current Equipment
0


2024-08-29 02:30:45
1001
Read Data
Liquid Point Read
10


2024-08-29 01:45:12
5000
Write Data
Liquid Point Set
50



Now, I want to be able to pivot this somehow to group my data by each unique timestamp and have each name as the column and the rows being the values of that name at that timestamp, something like this:



Timestamp
Current Equipment
Liquid Point Read
Liquid Point Set




2024-08-29 02:30:45
0
10



2024-08-29 01:45:12


50



I am not sure how to do this, if there's a way to transform the columns in this way using the transformations or anything else
I tried to find a way to just using KQL to transform the table after the merge because then I could easily pivot it but I couldn't find a way to be able to use the existing table that was formed after the merge and transform it using KQL.

When doing pivots, you want to make sure you only have the columns you need, and nothing else. In simple terms, Pivot is grouping all the rows that have the same values, and if you don't care about grouping against, in this case, Property, or Point, then you have to take them away from your data.
If you don't care about Property or Point, then that makes the query easy. You can just project them away, and call pivot on Name, and sum on Value.
let T = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, Property:int, Point:string, Name:string, Value:int)
[
    "2024-08-29 02:30:45", "1000", "Read Data", "Current Equipment", "0",
    "2024-08-29 02:30:45", "1001", "Read Data", "Liquid Point Read", "10",
    "2024-08-29 01:45:12", "5000", "Write Data", "Liquid Point Set", "50"
];
T
| project-away Property, Point
| evaluate pivot(Name, sum(Value))




Timestamp
Current Equipment
Liquid Point Read
Liquid Point Set




2024-08-29T01:45:12Z
0
0
50


2024-08-29T02:30:45Z
0
10
0




The issue with this is, I can't use KQL to pivot since I need to first get the names of the column from another query before I pivot, so I can't use KQL after that.

@ADUCJ I need more info here to understand what your scenario looks like. Are you calling an API to get some JSON blob data, then dumping it into a kusto table? From that table, you're then trying to pivot and dump it into another table? Are you expecting the column names to be different every time this gets run? Does the JSON data have a specific format?
